# laravel - most efficient way to insert an array of objects into a table using query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array of objects: `$groupedBySalesRegion` that contains about 4,000 elements.

I wish to insert `$groupedBySalesRegion` into a table `salesRegionSales`, mapping object properties to fields.

I want to use querybuilder to do it.  What's the most efficient way?

Comment: That many at once would probably hit the placeholder limit, so chunks are a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is in an appropriate format, use `insert()`:

```
DB::table('salesRegionSales')->insert($groupedBySalesRegion);
```